# Can we reverse which question is marked duplicate?

Tags: discussion

[What is the particular genre of the soundtrack in this music video?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/what-is-the-particular-genre-of-the-soundtrack-in-this-music-video)

We have two identical questions, with identical answers, but the one with an accepted answer is closed as a duplicate --the one marked original does not have an answer marked as accepted.  Can we reverse that?

Comment: Good idea... how could we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's worth it to have both since both questions and answers are the exact same. I'll reopen the duplicate and delete the other.

Answer (score 2):

Sure we should do that since the one with the accepted answer is original music fans and the other is migrated from musicians. User has posted the question in both at the same time.

The migration should have been declined in first place.